# Many issues trying to register webhooks for customs shopify app. Was working till it wasnt

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api, remix.run

My webhooks were going through the registration process just fine whenever I used `npm run dev -- --reset`, but now whenever I run it the `APP_UNINSTALLED` webhook fails to deliver and my other webhooks never get registered.  I can't figure out why this isnt working.

```
14:27:01 │ graphiql   │ GraphiQL server started on port 3457
14:27:03 │ webhooks   │ Sending APP_UNINSTALLED webhook to app server
14:27:06 │ webhooks   │ App isn't responding yet, retrying in 5 seconds
14:27:09 │ remix      │ 
14:27:09 │ remix      │    remix dev
14:27:09 │ remix      │ 
14:27:11 │ webhooks   │ App isn't responding yet, retrying in 5 seconds
14:27:12 │ remix      │  info  building...
14:27:15 │ remix      │  info  built (3.9s)
14:27:16 │ webhooks   │ App isn't responding yet, retrying in 5 seconds
14:27:18 │ remix      │ [shopify-api/INFO] version 9.2.0, environment Remix
14:27:21 │ webhooks   │ App hasn't started in time, giving up
14:27:21 │ webhooks   │ APP_UNINSTALLED webhook delivery failed
14:27:23 │ remix      │ [remix-serve] http://localhost:57473 (http://192.168.0.40:57473)
14:27:24 │ remix      │
```

I want the app to try and register the custom webhooks I have put in place at **shopify.server.js**

```
webhooks: {
    APP_UNINSTALLED: {
      deliveryMethod: DeliveryMethod.Http,
      callbackUrl: "/webhooks",
    },
    ORDERS_CREATE: {
      deliveryMethod: DeliveryMethod.Http,
      callbackUrl: "/webhooks",
    },
  },`
```

and at **webhooks.jsx**

```
switch (topic) {
    case "APP_UNINSTALLED":
      if (session) {
        console.log("App uninstalled", { shop });
        await db.session.deleteMany({ where: { shop } });
      }

      break;
    case "ORDERS_CREATE":
      if (session) {
        console.log("order created", payload);
        return new Response(`Created new order for ${shop}`, {status:200});
      }
      break;
    case "CUSTOMERS_DATA_REQUEST":
    case "CUSTOMERS_REDACT":
    case "SHOP_REDACT":
    default:
      throw new Response("Unhandled webhook topic", { status: 404 });
  }
```

This was working fine before, but now every time I try to run the damn thing the app cannot connect and deliver the webhook that is automatically called after `npm run dev -- --reset`.